# Getting MongoDB Result from Raw Query With Java

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get a feel for how fast MongoDB is compared to traditional RDBMSs.  To this end, I'm using Java to try and get the result of a traditional SQL join by defining a MongoDB function that will return an object after embedding another object into it:

```
s_with_user = function(rows){
  var result=[]
  db.subscriptions.find().limit(rows).forEach( function(s) { 
    s.user= db.users.find({id: s.user_id});
    result.push( s );
  });
  return result;
}
```

Then, I use:

```
DB db = new Mongo("localhost", 27017).getDB("test");
Object result = db.eval("s_with_user(1000)");
```

Measuring the time taken for the last statement, I'm confident that MongoDB is running the command and evaluating the data I want.  However, the `result` object is always `null`.

How can I do this in such a way that I can inspect the results?

Comment: Using `eval()` is not a good way to join .. this requires a write lock that will [block read/write operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution) to a database when executed.  In MongoDB a more typical approach would be to [embed](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) the related object directly in a document.  Alternatively you can run the equivalent "join" in your client code (i.e. iterating and merging the results).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Stennie is right about eval() not being the right way to do joins in MongoDB.

However, to try to answer your question, it would work this way:

```
   String f = "function(rows) { ... }";
   DB db = new Mongo("localhost", 27017).getDB("test");
   Object result = db.eval( f, 1000 );
```

Also, your "join" function needs a small correction: it should use `findOne` instead of `find`:

```
   s.user = db.users.findOne({id: s.user_id});
```